# Filtering filechooser via filename

Tags: java, swing, filter, filenames, jfilechooser

I learned how to use filter using filefilter.

```
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG file", "jpg", "jpeg");
```

But I want to filter my filechooser with files containing certain strings in them like having "sample" in their filenames.

Only files that does have these strings can be chosen and this filter must not be editable. How can I do it?

Comment: Write you own `FileFilter`. See [How to use file choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) and [Filtering the List of Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can i really filter it by filename?

Comment: Yes, the file extension is just part of the name.  You could even use regular expression if needed

Comment: @MadProgrammer I posted an answer, can you see if it is right?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Now that I've created it, how will I use it? I'd like the files that were filtered to appear in the filechooser

Comment: fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new ImageFilter());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ImageFilter extends FileFilter {

    //Accept all directories and all jpeg, jpg files with lossy in its filename.
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
        }

        String extension = Utils.getExtension(f);
        String filename = Utils.getName(f);
        if (extension != null) {
            if ((extension.equals(Utils.jpeg) || extension.equals(Utils.jpg)) && filename.contains("lossy")) {
                    return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    //The description of this filter
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Images (Lossy)";
    }
}
```

and this is my utils class

```
public class Utils {
    public final static String jpeg = "jpeg";
    public final static String jpg = "jpg";

/*
 * Get the extension of a file.
 */
    public static String getExtension(File f) {
        String ext = null;
        String s = f.getName();
        int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

        if (i > 0 &&  i < s.length() - 1) {
            ext = s.substring(i+1).toLowerCase();
        }
        return ext;
    }
    public static String getName(File f) {
        String fname = null;
        String s = f.getName();
        int i = s.length() - s.lastIndexOf('.');
        fname = s.substring(0,s.length()-i);

        return fname;
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = Utils.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

to apply,

```
fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new ImageFilter());
```

Comment: revised for getting right number of chars of extension in getName to get right number of chars of filename