# Exception in thread "Basic L&F File Loading Thread"

Tags: java, multithreading, loading, jfilechooser

When I run my code, sometimes, this error pops up whenever I use jfilechooser. imagefilter and utils that I've used are from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712786/filtering-filechooser-via-filename). I've searched this on on the net but I've only seen fixes like downgrading java.

My java is build `1.8.0_25-b18` and is currently using `netbeans 8.0.2` as my `IDE`.

```
Exception in thread "Basic L&F File Loading Thread" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1954)
    at datacomparison.Utils.getName(Utils.java:36)
    at datacomparison.ImageFilter.accept(ImageFilter.java:27)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.accept(JFileChooser.java:1650)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel$LoadFilesThread.run0(BasicDirectoryModel.java:252)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel$LoadFilesThread.run(BasicDirectoryModel.java:228)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the Util.getName() method (in the code you have linked to), if there is no period in the filename, then lastIndexOf() returns a -1 and StringIndexOutOfBounds will occur in the next line.  I can't tell if this is what's happening in your case, there's not enough information, but it looks possible.  Whoever wrote that code didn't plan on a case where a filename has no period.

Next time, put all the necessary code into your question, not a link to code elsewhere.

Comment: There is always a period because all files I am using do have an extension. I am just curious for the exception on Basic L&F File Loading Thread

Comment: This is why some posters here insist on a small executable example that illustrates your problem.  You don't give source, you don't even give the filename on which this fails, you're "just curious".  You don't indicate that you've tried to debug it.  I can't help without more information.